# How to create multiple sequences of varying lengths with arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

Let's say I have a list of 3 values in a column A. The amount of values is arbitrary, so there can be more. So for example:

```
 |A|B
-+-+-
1|4|
2|2|
3|3|
```

In the column B, I would like to get a sequence, which would include increasing sequences with the lengths of the values given in column A. So the above example would be:

```
The expected sequences:
4 = 1,2,3,4
2 = 1,2
3 = 1,2,3

The expected table:

  A|B
---+-
1|4|1
2|2|2
3|3|3
4| |4
5| |1
6| |2
7| |1
8| |2
9| |3
```

I am currently achieving this by having the following function in B1: `={SEQUENCE(A1);SEQUENCE(A2);SEQUENCE(A3)}` but as you can see, if I were to add another value to the column A, I would need to modify the said function. How can I achieve this dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach (for google sheets). In B1

```
=Arrayformula(transpose(split(textjoin("~", 1, if(column(1:1)<=A1:A, column(1:1),)), "~")))
```

[image]

Comment: That seems to do the trick. However, if I have an "empty" field with "", it gives me a sequence which is long as there are columns in the document. Fixed it by leaving it empty instead. Not an issue but good to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

say your data starts at A2, then use the following formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( transpose( split( join("\", LEFT(join( "\", COLUMN(offset($A$1,,,,max($A2:$A))) ), offset($A$2,,,COUNT($A2:$A))*2-1) ) ,"\") ) )
```

in cell B2. Mind that if you have numbers >= 10 then special care must be taken with text( ... ,"00") and *2 --> *3 and so on, accordingly if you expect for >=100...